# UINavigationController and presenting a modal controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

If got a rootViewController which display's a UIScrollView full screen. When I tap the UIScrollview, I want to flip the screen and display a settings screen (which also has a second screen, the reason for the navigationController).

I am able to display the settings screen by using the following code in my rootViewController:

`self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:self.settingsViewController];`

and than:

`[self.navController pushViewController:self.settingsViewController animated:YES];`

My question is: When I'm done in my settings view, how do I return back to the rootViewController, so the controller class in which I have created the navigation Controller and is therefore not on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adopted Apple's solution which they use in the [Metronome example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Metronome/Introduction/Intro.html).

I'm setting the settingsViewController as the rootViewController for a navigationController. Than I display the navigationController using:

`[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];`

As per apple's example, I've created a settingsViewControllerDelegate interface which the rootViewController adopts. The interface is not complicated, just a delegate instance var and a callback method (settingsViewControllerDidFinish) which needs to be implemented by rootViewController. In that methode you call:

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

This way I'm able to have a couple of settings-screens using a navigationController and I'm able to return out of the navigationController back to the rootViewController.

Comment: I think I'm trying exactly what you did, but can't find the sample code you have written about. Can you help me find it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610950/instantiating-uinavigationcontroller-from-viewcontroller